# Google map listing similar to Airbnb

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I hope that someone kindly can help me. I have not the sufficient knowledge of google api and jquery to implement what i need.

I have a google map, you can see a demo here http://divinethemes.eu/map/
the script works with infobox, each point is filtered by a category, etc.

What I need is to have the possibility to give some actions from an outside map list (from the HTML): open the bubble of a specific point (and close already opened +  center the map) or bounce a bubble or highlight a specific marker. My intention is create a similar (more simple) google map locations listing like Airbnb. can be great if in the HTML listing outside the map each point can be an href that open the specific bubble via and id or data attribute...like "name_point". but I don't know how to do it...

Here's the code of the map:

```
(function(A) {

    if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
        A.forEach = A.forEach || function(action, that) {
                for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
                    if (i in this)
                        action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
            };

})(Array.prototype);

var
    mapObject,
    markers = [],
    markersData = {
        'Bars': [
            {
                type_point: 'Wine bar',
                location_latitude: 43.773781,
                location_longitude: 11.257206,
                map_image_url: 'img/thumb_map_2.jpg',
                rate: 'Superb 7.5',
                name_point: 'Astor Cafe',
                description_point: 'Piazza del Duomo, 20/R',
                get_directions_start_address: '43.773460, 11.255985',
                phone: '+3934245255',
                url_detail: 'single_tour.html'
            },
            {
                type_point: 'Pub - Wine bar',
                location_latitude: 43.772238,
                location_longitude: 11.252205,
                map_image_url: 'img/thumb_map_3.jpg',
                rate: 'Superb 7.5',
                name_point: 'Uncle Jimmy',
                description_point: 'Via dei Pescioni,10',
                get_directions_start_address: '43.773460, 11.255985',
                phone: '+3934245255',
                url_detail: 'single_tour.html'
            }
        ]

    };


var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.773460, 11.255985),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
    },
    panControl: false,
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    scrollwheel: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scaleControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },

};

var marker;
mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
for (var key in markersData)
    markersData[key].forEach(function (item) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude),
            map: mapObject,
            icon: 'img/pins/' + key + '.png',
        });

        if ('undefined' === typeof markers[key])
            markers[key] = [];
        markers[key].push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function () {
            closeInfoBox();
            getInfoBox(item).open(mapObject, this);
            mapObject.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(item.location_latitude, item.location_longitude));
        }));

    });

function hideAllMarkers () {
    for (var key in markers)
        markers[key].forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
};

function closeInfoBox() {
    $('div.infoBox').remove();
};

function getInfoBox(item) {
    return new InfoBox({
        content:
        '<div class="marker_info" id="marker_info">' +
        '<img src="' + item.map_image_url + '" alt=""/>' +
        '<span>'+
        '<span class="infobox_rate">'+ item.rate +'</span>' +
        '<h3>'+ item.name_point +'</h3>' +
        '<em>'+ item.type_point +'</em>' +
        '<strong>'+ item.description_point +'</strong>' +
        '<a href="'+ item.url_detail + '" class="btn_infobox_detail"></a>' +
        '<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank"><input name="saddr" value="'+ item.get_directions_start_address +'" type="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="'+ item.location_latitude +',' +item.location_longitude +'"><button type="submit" value="Get directions" class="btn_infobox_get_directions">Get directions</button></form>' +
        '<a href="tel://'+ item.phone +'" class="btn_infobox_phone">'+ item.phone +'</a>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</div>',
        disableAutoPan: true,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(35, -175),
        closeBoxMargin: '5px -28px 0 0',
        closeBoxURL: "img/close_infobox.png",
        isHidden: false,
        pane: 'floatPane',
        enableEventPropagation: true
    });
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps, open info window after click on a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333679/google-maps-open-info-window-after-click-on-a-link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps v3 open infowindow from a link outside of map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078464/google-maps-v3-open-infowindow-from-a-link-outside-of-map)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you keep reference of all your markers in `markers` array. You can trigger `click` event on any marker to simulate click on it. That way, the infobox would open for marker and map would be centered there.

So, create a function like:

```
function onHtmlClick(key){
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[key], "click");
}
```

where `key` is the index of the marker you want to bring up popup for in the `markers` array.

On your html elements you would just call the function, something like:

```
<div onclick="onHtmlClick(1)">...</div>
```

**EDIT!**

It looks like in your code, the `markers` array has following structure:

```
[ LOCATION_TYPE_1: [ MARKER, MARKER,..], LOCATION_TYPE_2: [ MARKER4, MARKER,..]
```

That means you have to update the `onclick` listener and function:

```
<div onclick="onHtmlClick('Bars', 1)">...</div> 


function onHtmlClick(location_type, key){
     google.maps.event.trigger(markers[location_type][key], "click");
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mow89utv/2/

Comment: I have edited my answer. It includes working fiddle.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please accept/upvote the answer if it solved your problem.